# How do I change the launch position of Git Bash for Windows?

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, mintty

Whenever I launch the Git Bash window, it always starts at the upper left corner of the screen, so I have to drag it to the center to see it clearly.

Is there a way to change the default launch position, so that I don't have to drag it every time I launch it?

Essentially I'm looking for a Windows's solution to this: [How can I set gnome-terminal's X and Y startup position?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773383/how-can-i-set-gnome-terminals-x-and-y-startup-position)

Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to `C:\Users\username\.minttyrc`

2. Specify the x and y position in two new lines like this:

```
X=300
Y=300
```

3. Save for it to take effect.

Comment: omg thank you for this answer! It wasn't easy to find, and works perfectly!

Comment: Just to add a small addendum, if you don't see the `.minttyrc` there you can just create the file and add the text above.

Comment: it doesn't work for me on windows 10 (i use a shortcut on my toolbar to git-bash.exe), my version is 2.38.1.